# how to get the attribute of an element as a text type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the case,
 I get the element's id by using `this.attributes.getNamedItem("id");`. `this` means the pic I've selected and I have couples of images.

I want to get the number from the `id` of the selected image because I want to use the number as a counter. For example, here the id is `img_4`, but it seems not a text type. I hope to get the `id` as a text or string, and then get the last character, and then change it, which is `4`, to a number. Can you please tell any ways to do it?

Cheers

Comment: Why not using `this.id`?

Comment: Please show all relevant code. We can't troubleshoot code we can't see

Comment: Where you getting the values for HTML , XML ? Are you able to post a little code to help with visualising it etc? Could you not wrap it araounf a `String(value)` then `string.slice(-1)`to get the last char, then `parseInt(value)`

Comment: I'm going through some older answers of mine, and found this. How doesn't my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

With the regex `match` it doesn't matter, if later the number will be in the middle, as it will still work.

```js
    var el = document.getElementById("img_4");
    var nr = parseInt(el.id.match(/\d/g));
    
    el.textContent = 'Your number ' + nr + ' plus 3 equals ' + (nr + 3);
```

```html
<div id="img_4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `this.attributes.getNamedItem("id");` or `this.id` will give you the `id` of the element as a string. If you want to convert it to a number, you can use the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function in combination with the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function:

```
var imageID = "img_4"; // or this.id
var imageIndexString = imageID.split("_")[1]; // the text after the _, "4"
var imageIndex = parseInt(imageIndexString); // string "4" is now a number: 4
```